# Weight painting models with loose parts

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have an awful lot of models to rig, and most of them have lots of loose parts in each mesh that function as hairs when used with a toon shader. My issue is that when I apply an automatic weight paint the geometry is painted very erratically, almost at random. If they were slightly off they could be tweaked, but most are paired to completely wrong bones on the other side of the armature.

Does anybody know of a better process? Or a way I can get the auto-painter to recognise the loose geometry as part of the whole mesh?

[image: Loose parts example]

Answer (score 1):

Automatic weighting gets confused when a mesh is not continuous, non-manifold, with intersections and so on ...

You could separate all your loose parts (P, in edit mode), do the automatic weights on the base mesh, then manually parent the loose parts with their respective bones, then join all the meshes, selecting the base mesh as last (Active) and pressing Ctrl J.

Comment: thanks for your reply, after some experimenting it seems to work better if you auto paint the base mesh and a "loose parts" mesh separately